# unable to login in raspberry.. please help me out

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I changed in setting under sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="in"

I know i made some mistakes here "in" is not any standard but after rebooting my system am unable to login in my device
 please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you have changed the keyboard layout meaning that it would likely be using a different keyboard layout which uses different keys.

To fix I would think that logging in via SSH on another computer should work (This can be done by using a tool like Putty on windows) or just ssh into the Linux Terminal (I think this also works for Macs).
After you are logged in run sudo raspi-config and then configure the keyboard layout / locale back to whatever language the keyboard is in.

Answer (score 0):

Ryanteck is right, you're likely to now have an incorrect setup. Logging in through SSH will use your local keyboard setting so you should be able to set the default keyboard back to wht it was.

Heres a link about [setting default keyboard](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_keyboard_layouts_in_X) for X, should help

Heres a link to [setting up and configuring SSH on RPi](http://www.pauljoyceuk.com/codex/2013/raspberry-pi-configuring-and-connecting-with-ssh/)